# ng-boostrap : modal dismiss on ESC keypress not working

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I want to dismiss MODAL on the keypress of ESC. **But it isn't working...**
 As I see on ng-bootstrap docs, By default `keyboard` is `true`. But even it isn't working...

I have applied `ngbAutofocus` on `.modal-body` class as **I don't want default autofocus on close button** because **I had a animation on the focus of close button as well as animation on "ACCEPT" button**.

I have attached the link of my code [here...](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng-boostrap-modal-esc-keypress-not-working)

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The focus should be somewhere in the modal for `esc` to work. I see you added `ngbAutofocus` directive to the `div` element. the problem is - `div` is not focusable unless it has `tabindex` attribute. Adding this attribute will solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you... @IAfanasov Now model gets dismissed on `ESC` keypress. I also understood what you told in the solution.